# g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop problem

Tags: c, gtk

I am using the following code to run a function in another thread:

```
void load (....)
{
    GIOSchedulerJob *job;
    g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop(job,(GSourceFunc)job_func,&param, g_free);
}

    gboolean job_func(GIOSchedulerJob *job, GSourceFunc func, gpointer user_data, GDestroyNotify notify)
    {       
        JobParam* job_param = (JobParam*)user_data; 
        build(job_param->widget, job_param->mw);
        return TRUE;
    }
```

But when I try to call `g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop` I get an error: `g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop: assertion 'job != NULL' failed`.

How can I initialize job, or can I fix the issue?

Comment: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Memory-Allocation.html

Comment: Can you explain more in detail, what should I sddelat? Allocate a job? How?

Comment: just a question, are you trying to figure out the answer to your previous question [gtk+ multithreading image loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094888/gtk-multithreading-image-loading)? I was trying to think of an answer for it, but I was also wondering why you'd need to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the is obviously related to your previous question [C attempt to difference a generic pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119099/c-attempt-to-difference-a-generic-pointer)

I'm going to say I think you're using the GIO job mechanism wrong (and using it for the wrong reasons as well), if you give some more detail about what you are trying to do and WHY you want to do it async someone might be able to give you a better answer, if you're still doing the same thing in `build()` you were before, that's STILL a problem with your code, if you're leaving things out of the code you posted, please put some comments in explaining vaguely what it would have been doing.

You haven't really given enough detail to give a proper answer. (and your code this time around seems to be LESS correct than last time)

g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop is to push a bit of work that needs to be done on the main thread, as part of a job that is already in progress, the GIOSchedulerJob is passed to your `load();` by GIO when you kick of some async work with `g_io_scheduler_push_job()`. For example load could be something like:

```
gboolean load(GIOSchedulerJob *job, GCancellable *cancellable, gpointer user_data)
{
    // load a bunch of data and stuff it into param, or wherever

    g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop(job,(GSourceFunc)job_func, &param, g_free);
    return TRUE;
}

gboolean job_func(gpointer user_data)
{       
    JobParam* job_param = (JobParam*)user_data; 
    build(job_param->widget, job_param->mw);
    return TRUE;
}
```

But fundamentally you are using the API wrong, `job_func()` shouldn't have the same type as `g_io_scheduler_job_send_to_mainloop()`

Also this didn't really need to be a new question, you could have edited your previous one.